# Using antispambot() on phone numbers?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any value to using the WordPress function antispambot() when displaying phone numbers? Or are there any downsides to doing so?

In the codex, all the examples provided are for email addresses:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/antispambot

The function seems to work just fine for phone numbers as I've played with it, but I've not seen anyone suggest it for that purpose.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Want to prominently feature a phone number on a business' marketing site and they expressed some concern about whether or not it may increase the number of robocalls they receive. Since antispambot() seems to help with that same problem on email I was thinking of just adding it to phone numbers as well.

Answer (score 3):

It should work fine. It just displays the phone number has an HTML entity. Theoretically a spambot could reverse this, but they'd have to know what they're looking for.